# How to use multiple pattern with the condition

Tags: json, linux, parsing, awk

The input text in test.txt file:

```
{"col1":"250000","col2":"8089389","col4":"09876545","col3":"121","col5":"123456789"}
{"col1":"210000","col3":"112","col2":"8089389","col4":"09876545","col5":"123456789"}
{"col1":"120000","col2":"8089389","col3":"123","col4":"09876545","col5":"123456789"}
{"col1":"170000","col2":"8089389","col4":"09876545","col5":"123456789","col3":"123"}
{"col1":"190000","col2":"8089389","col4":"09876545","col5":"123456789,"col3":"124""}
{"col3":"176","col1":"220000","col2":"8089389","col4":"09876545","col5":"123456789"}
```

The command line and result that i tried:

```
$ awk -F"," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /col1/){print $i} };for (x=1;x<=NF;x++){if($x ~ /col3/){print $x}}}' test.txt
{"col1":"250000"
"col3":"121"
{"col1":"210000"
"col3":"112"
{"col1":"120000"
"col3":"123"
{"col1":"170000"
"col3":"123"
{"col1":"190000"
"col3":"124"
{"col1":"220000"
"col3":"176"
```

The expected result that i would like to get:

```
col1:250000,col3:121
col1:210000,col3:112
col1:120000,col3:123
col1:170000,col3:123
col1:190000,col3:124
col1:220000,col3:176
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are parsing a `json` file. You can use `jq`,

```
$ jq --raw-output '"col1:" + .col1 + ",col3:" + .col3' file.json
col1:250000,col3:121
col1:210000,col3:112
col1:120000,col3:123
col1:170000,col3:123
col1:190000,col3:124
col1:220000,col3:176
```

For more info: [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/)

Comment: Unfortunately there is not jq on my server and i have not the permission to install it. Any idea with awk ?

Comment: @RafaelNguyen, No need to install it. You can get pre-compiled binary [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk  '{gsub(/\{|\"|\}|\;/,"");match($0,/col1[^,]*/);VAL1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)",";match($0,/col3[^,]*/);VAL2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);if(VAL1 && VAL2){print VAL1 VAL2}}'  Input_file
```

I am globally substituting the characters {}"; in the line and then looking for a match for col1 and col3 strings in each line and if both the col1 and col3 strings are present then printing them.

**EDIT:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk  '{
        gsub(/\{|\"|\}|\;/,"");
        match($0,/col1[^,]*/);
        VAL1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)",";
        match($0,/col3[^,]*/);
        VAL2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
        if(VAL1 && VAL2){
                                print VAL1 VAL2
                        }
      }
     '   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

if missing `json` tools, here is an `awk` hack

```
$ awk -F'[:,]' -v OFS=, -v cols='col1,col3' '
       {n=split(cols,c); 
        gsub(/[{}"]/,""); 
        for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) a[$i]=$(i+1); 
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%s", (c[i]":"a[c[i]]), (i==n?ORS:OFS)}' file

col1:250000,col3:121
col1:210000,col3:112
col1:120000,col3:123
col1:170000,col3:123
col1:190000,col3:124
col1:220000,col3:176
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're manipulating data that has name->value mappings, it's best to first create an associative array to store that mapping (`n2v[]` below) and then you can just print whatever values you want by looking them up in the array by their name.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS="}"; FS="\""; OFS="," }
{
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=4) {
        n2v[$i] = $(i+2)
    }
    print p("col1"), p("col3")
}
function p(n) { return (n ":" n2v[n]) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
col1:250000,col3:121
col1:210000,col3:112
col1:120000,col3:123
col1:170000,col3:123
col1:190000,col3:123
col1:220000,col3:176
col1:220000,col3:176
```